# YouTube API v2 /feeds/api/videos/VIDEOID fails after 200+ requests: 400 Bad Request

Tags: youtube-api, feed, bad-request

I've got about 7000 videos published and need to make about 500 of them 'unlisted'. First I want to walk the list of those videos and look at their current 'access' 'action' 'listed' status.

I use the YouTube V2 API, do an OAUTH authentication to my content.  Then I loop over the list of video IDs with this query:

```
    url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + youtube_id + '?alt=json'
```

and after about 214 requests, all the subsequent ones fail:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
    <H1>Bad Request</H1>
    <H2>Error 400</H2>
  </BODY>
</HTML>

headers={'status': '400', 'content-length': '145', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'expires': 'Fri, 21 Jun 2013 20:08:28 GMT', 'server': 'GSE', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'date': 'Fri, 21 Jun 2013 20:08:28 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}
```

There are no details about why this, and the remaining ~300, fail.

This is repeatable, if I rerun it dies after the 214th again and again. If I start midway through the sequence, skipping the first 212, it dies at 426th video -- so it's not video #215 that is having issues in isolation.

This sounds like I'm reaching a quota, but we've got ours bumped up, and the API console shows us nowhere near our limit.

Any ideas?

I haven't even started writing changes yet, so this is worrisome.
Thanks.

Comment: Please do not add `solved` to the title of questions. Instead, post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Before running the queries against the API, I had logged in with OAUTH and created an HTTP request object.  My fix was to periodically re-invoke the login, which I now do every 10th query -- this seems to be enough.

FWIW, my authentication routine (based on Posnick's examples) and invocation looks like this:

```
class YouTubeV2(object):
    """Authenticate to APIv2 and do stuff we can't do with v3, like captions
    """
    OAUTH_SCOPE = "https://gdata.youtube.com"

    def __init__(self, client_id, client_secret, developer_key):
        """OAuth authenticates, creates 'http' attribute to make a .request().

        Get client_id, client secret from: http://code.google.com/apis/console
        Get developer_key from: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard
        """
        # This auth code is generic and should be used for any APIv2 calls.
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret
        self.developer_key = developer_key
        self.headers = {'GData-Version': '2',
                        'X-GData-Key': 'key=%s' % self.developer_key}
        storage = Storage("%s-oauth" % sys.argv[0])
        self.credentials = storage.get()
        if self.credentials is None or self.credentials.invalid:
            # If there are no valid cached credentials, take the user through the
            # OAuth2 login flow, and rely on the client library to cache the
            # credentials once that's complete.
            flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
                client_id=self.client_id,
                client_secret=self.client_secret,
                scope=self.OAUTH_SCOPE,
                user_agent=sys.argv[0])
            self.credentials = run(flow, storage)
        self.http = self.credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

yt2 = YouTubeV2(client_id, client_secret, developer_key)
```